# MSSQL. Is it possible to execute bulk MERGE ignoring failures?

Tags: sql-server, merge

Suppose we have a simple relationship between two tables (Products and Categories)
[image]

And they contain following data:

[image]

And I want to do a SQL MERGE operation on the `dbo.Products` table from a temporary table, which has following records:

[image]

SQL Merge:

```
-- Declare Temporary Table to read from
SELECT TOP 0 T.*, [Index]= CAST(0 AS int)  INTO [#ProductsTempSource] 
FROM [Products] AS T 
LEFT JOIN [Products]
ON 1 = 0;

-- Insert Values to temporary table
INSERT INTO [#ProductsTempSource] ([Id],[Name],[CategoryId], [Index])  VALUES (1, 'Pork1', 1, 0)
INSERT INTO [#ProductsTempSource] ([Id],[Name],[CategoryId], [Index])  VALUES (2, 'Beef',  3, 1) -- << Note 3 is missing categoryId

-- Execute SQL MERGE
MERGE INTO [Products]  AS DestinationTable
USING (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [#ProductsTempSource] ORDER BY [Index]) AS StagingTable 
ON DestinationTable.[Id] = StagingTable.[Id]
WHEN MATCHED     THEN
UPDATE
SET     [CategoryId] = StagingTable.[CategoryId], [Name] = StagingTable.[Name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ( [CategoryId], [Name] )
VALUES ( [CategoryId], [Name] )
OUTPUT
    $action,
    StagingTable.[Index],
    DELETED.[Id] AS [Id_deleted], DELETED.[Name] AS [Name_deleted], DELETED.[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId_deleted],
    INSERTED.[Id] AS [Id_inserted], INSERTED.[Name] AS [Name_inserted], INSERTED.[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId_inserted]
;
```

If I execute the query as is it will fail because of FK Key constraint:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 15
> The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "SqlMergeDemoDb", table "dbo.Categories", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

### Problem Statement:

What I want to achieve is avoid ALL-OR-NOTHING approach, and do a MERGE in a "best effort" way and accept partial success of records that can be merged, and collect maybe failures in a separate table, or output them? Is this possible using MERGE statement?

[Here is a fiddle with DDL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/181ca/9)

Comment: Have you considered joining the temp table to Categories so that the source query will return only valid categories?

Comment: Yes, pre-filtering was always an option, before feeding the temp table. However I'm wondering if its possible without?

Comment: A single SQL statement is atomic - it either succeeds or does not. So the short answer is no. Workarounds exist by changing your approach - but you did not ask that question. Generally speaking, ETL is best left to tools that are designed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @CristianE., I mean `USING (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [#ProductsTempSource] AS t JOIN Categories AS c ON c.CategoryId = t.CategoryId ORDER BY [Index]) AS StagingTable`

Answer (score 2):

You can just join `Categories.Id`, which means that all rows that do not have a correct category will be excluded.

```sql
MERGE INTO [Products]  AS DestinationTable
USING (
    SELECT TOP (100) pts.*
    FROM [#ProductsTempSource] pts
    WHERE pts.CategoryId IN (
        SELECT c.Id FROM dbo.Categories c
    )
-- alternatively
 -- JOIN dbo.Categories c ON c.Id = pts.CategoryId
    ORDER BY [Index]
) AS StagingTable 
ON DestinationTable.[Id] = StagingTable.[Id]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
      [CategoryId] = StagingTable.[CategoryId],
      [Name] = StagingTable.[Name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( [CategoryId], [Name] )
    VALUES ( [CategoryId], [Name] )
OUTPUT
    $action,
    StagingTable.[Index],
    DELETED.[Id] AS [Id_deleted], DELETED.[Name] AS [Name_deleted], DELETED.[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId_deleted],
    INSERTED.[Id] AS [Id_inserted], INSERTED.[Name] AS [Name_inserted], INSERTED.[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId_inserted]
;
```